# Multiline text in a <div> with normal word-wrap : how to make it longer at the bottom?

Tags: css, word-wrap

Let's say I have a **`<div>`** that has some predefined long headline in it. The **`<div>`** has a fixed max-width, so that longer text gets broken into two lines.

**`<div> LOONG HEADLINE FOR SOME WEBSITE </div>`**

The **`max-width`** of this **`<div>`** is set to some value that forces the text to be broken in two lines. The question is, for a word combination where the last word of the upper line can be placed both on the upper line and lower line, how can I make the bottom line "heavier" (that is, place that word on the bottom line)?

As an illustration, with **standard styling**, the word-wrap I get is:

```
========================
|                      |
|  LOONG HEADLINE FOR  |
|     SOME WEBSITE     |
|                      |
========================
```

while the **desired word-wrap** would be:

```
========================
|                      |
|    LOONG HEADLINE    |
|   FOR SOME WEBSITE   |
|                      |
========================
```

I understand that setting for example **`padding-left`** and **`padding-right`** could be helpful, but I also want normal, precisely fitting into the div headlines to **not** be broken into two lines:

```
========================
|                      |
|HEADLINE FITS THE DIV!|
|                      |
========================
```

There is also no way to know/set the number of lines in the text. It should be done automatically, so I can't for instance use two **`<h>`** elements, each for a single line, nor can I force **`<br>`** into the text.

Comment: Can you use a backend scripting language for this project? (e.g. PHP) Or can you use Javascript?

Comment: Also is the max-width variable or will it be a known value?

Comment: can **<wbr>** help you? http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_wbr.asp

Comment: My guess is that this solution is going to be a little complicated

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob - the text is being added via  web content and the HTML template is generated in FreeMarker. And I can use JavaScript in the project. Max-width I  chose based on a photoshop-created mockup.

Comment: @Vixed I will think about what I can do with **<wbr>**, but I said before that I can't insert **<br>** s into the text.

Comment: but you can't edit html at all?

Comment: @Vixed I can, question is, how to determine the place where to put this **<wbr>**? When does this situation (one-word-can-be-placed-on-both-lines) occur?

Comment: but do you know where you have to put wbr? I mean, will you code any long contents?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a dummy div into the DOM:

```
#dummy-div { position:absolute; z-index: 100; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; /* div is off the screen */ }
```

Now some jQuery:

```
var container_text = $("#long_message_div").text();
$("#dummy-div").html(container_text);
```

Now get the dummy width:

```
var dummy_width = $("#dummy-div").width();
```

Now compare the max-width of the desired container and the dummy_width:

```
if (dummy_width > your_max_width) {
    //want more content on bottom
    if (container_text.match(/\s/)) {
        //white spaces imply word boundaries - so split on white spaces
        var split_array = container_text.split(" "),
            split_length = split_array.length;

        //Now reformat the container's text to insert a line break less than halfway between.

        var less_than_half = Math.floor(split_length / 2);
        //Now form and insert the new content
        var i = 0, newContent = '';

        for(; i < split_length; i++) {
            newContent += split_array[i] + (i !== less_than_half ? ' ' : '<br>');
        }

        document.getElementById("long_message_div").innerHTML = newContent;

    } else {
        // otherwise this is a long unbroken string so just word wrap
    }
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Hi really like tour answer, but the problem is that he doesn't know which is the #long_message_div so his question is a crap.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I don't know to show you on a mobile dev, but assuming that you have a max-width of 200px, here is my answer.

```css
div{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  max-width:200px;
  min-height:60px;
  border:1px dotted #000;
  margin:10px auto;
}

span{
  white-space:pre;
  /*but I really don't know why white-space doesn't maintain the with*/
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div><span>LOONG HEADLINE FOR SOME WEBSITE</span></div>
<div><span>LOONG HEADLINE <wbr />FOR SOME WEBSITE</span></div>
<div><span>HEADLINE FITS THE DIV!</span></div>
```

Comment: When I run the snippet, it shows the same wrong wrapping for the first two divs...

Comment: but do you know where you have to put wbr? I mean, will you code any long contents?

Comment: I told you before, I **don't** know in advance where to put the **<br>**

Comment: so how do you know where you have to break?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vertical-align: bottom;` on your div